# catkin_make error

Tags: catkin-make, rosjava, cmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of running catkin_make, but right before make is successful, I am receiving the following error with a gradle plugin:

:gradle_plugins:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
:gradle_plugins:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:gradle_plugins:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:gradle_plugins:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:gradle_plugins:classes UP-TO-DATE
:gradle_plugins:jar UP-TO-DATE
:gradle_plugins:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
Uploading: org/ros/rosjava_bootstrap/gradle_plugins/0.1.18/gradle_plugins-0.1.18.jar to repository remote at file:/opt  /ros/hydro/share/maven/
Transferring 91K from remote
/opt/ros/hydro/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_bootstrap/gradle_plugins/0.1.18/gradle_plugins-0.1.18.jar (Permission denied)
:gradle_plugins:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle_plugins:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'.

> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
> Error deploying artifact 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:jar': Error deploying artifact: PUT request to: org/ros  /rosjava_bootstrap/gradle_plugins/0.1.18/gradle_plugins-0.1.18.jar in remote failed

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.368 secs
make[2]: *** [rosjava_bootstrap/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_bootstrap] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rosjava_bootstrap/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_bootstrap.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

Since the error mentioned permission being denied to the folder, I tried changing the permissions.  I even used "chmod -R 777 filename(s)" but when I used catkin_make, I still received the same error.
Are there any possible workarounds or fixes for this issue?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138681/catkin_make-error/) by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's trying to upload to `file:/opt /ros/hydro/share/maven/` which indicates something is going wrong. catkin_make should only ever attempt to upload to your devel workspace (e.g. `~/my_workspace/devel/share/maven`). Are your environment variables pointing to the right places? What does `env | grep ROS` show for you?

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-03-12**:
No my env. variables were not pointing to the correct places.
I changed the ROS_MAVEN_PATH and ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY from /opt/ros/hydro/share/maven to ....../devel/share/maven using the export command, and my build was successful. Thanks!

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2017-11-03**:
Hey musk,
I am confronting the same error. Can you explain how you mean by saying I changed the ROS_MAVEN_PATH and ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY from /opt/ros/hydro/share/maven to ....../devel/share/maven